# Android OkHttpClient POST\PUT requests received as GET

Tags: android

I'm trying to send post/put request to my service using OkHttp library.

```
private static final String SERVICE = "service_url";
private static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("text/json");

private OkHttpClient mClient = new OkHttpClient();
//---------------------------------------------------------------
Request req = new Request.Builder()
                .url(SERVICE)
                .put(RequestBody.create(JSON, body))
                .build();
        try {
            Response httpResp = mClient.newCall(req).execute();
            resp = httpResp.body().string();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But this code sends GET request, not PUT. The same situation will be if I use .post.
I was trying to use HttpURLConnection and I've got the same result.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As all libraries are different so cannot say much about **OkHttpClient**. I personally use **[basic-http-client](https://github.com/turbomanage/basic-http-client)** and did lots of post requests. If you are just started I would say give **basic-http-client** a try. Its also **not deprecated** in lollipop.

Comment: Please tell how you know that a GET request is received.

Comment: Your subject is confusing. Please change to 'OkHttpClient POST\PUT requests received as GET'.

Comment: I have access to the server. And it is noted that GET request has been received in its log.

Comment: I've tested basic-http-client. The same result.